# Paul octopus algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm using java that similar to Paul's prediction. It looks like if we give two numbers to the algorithm, it will give one number randomly from those two numbers.

Comment: You could have asked him while he was still alive.

Comment: You're probably interested in Number Guessing algorithms, Google is your best friend.

Comment: Now called `the sushi algorithm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is good .....

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        double left = Math.random();

        System.out.println("left : "+left);

        double right =  Math.random();

        System.out.println("right : "+right);

        System.out.println(pickOne(left, right));
    }

    public static double pickOne(double left, double right) {
        return Math.random() < Math.random() ? left : right;
    }
```

Comment: In theory `Math.random() < Math.random()` should returns slightly more 'false' than 'true' because the values could be equal as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell exactly what you want from your question, but it seems like either you want something like:

```
public static int pickOne(int left, int right) {
    return Math.random() < 0.5 ? left : right;
}
```

Or:

```
public static int pickRandomFromRange(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
    return (int)(Math.random() * upperBound) + lowerBound;
}
```

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        double left = Math.random();

        System.out.println("left : "+left);
        
        double right =  Math.random();

        System.out.println("right : "+right);

        System.out.println(pickOne(left, right));
    }

    public static double pickOne(double left, double right) {
        return Math.random() < Math.random() ? left : right;
    }